# Expected score in my first FIDE tournament

Tags: rating, tournament, elo, fide

Going to play my first international tournament next week.

As this is my first I do not have a FIDE ELO (I have national rating however).

How will my games be rated and how is my expected score for each game calculated?

Answer (score 4):

The [FIDE Rating Regulations](http://www.fide.com/component/handbook/?id=172&view=article) give details of how the system works. You should scroll down to section **8. The working of the FIDE Rating System**
which describes the mathematical tables and formulae used for calculating ratings.

Note that a fudge factor called the "Development Coefficient" is used in calculating ratings which determines by how much new results affect your existing rating once you have one.

> K = 40 for a player new to the rating list until he has completed
>   events with at least 30 games
>
> K = 20 as long as a player's rating remains under 2400.
>
> K = 10 once a player's published rating has reached 2400 and remains
>   at that level subsequently, even if the rating drops below 2400.
>
> K = 40 for all players until their 18th birthday, as long as their
>   rating remains under 2300.

As a new player you will have a high K which will mean that your rating will change rapidly if you have results which vary widely from your previous results.

Comment: +1. If you "play it well", the rating can grow very rapidly due to the K-factor... For example, there has been a case recently, where a kid (Parviz Gasimov) went from ~1950 to >2500 in a matter of few months/tournaments. https://chess24.com/en/read/news/from-1949-to-2517-in-three-months

Comment: This question gives the link to the regulations but the different K factors don't have anything to do with a new player's rating after his first tournament.

Comment: Sorry - but this does not answer my question. What does K mean? I thought I would get an established FIDE rating after 9 games? What is my opponents expected score against me as I have no rating?

Answer (score 2):

If you're unrated, you don't really have an expected score. How can anything be expected when your rating is totally unknown? But the win expectancy table is sometimes used in *reverse*, to calculate the rating of an unrated player based on the *actual* score.

There are actually a few different formulas that might be used to determine your initial rating, depending on the type of tournament and your score, according to the [FIDE Ratings Regulations](http://www.fide.com/component/handbook/?id=197&view=article):

> 8.2 Determining the Rating 'Ru' in a given event of a previously unrated player.
>
> 8.21 If an unrated player scores zero in his first event his score is disregarded.
>   First determine the average rating of his competition 'Rc'.
>
> (a) In a Swiss or Team tournament: this is simply the average rating of his opponents.
>
> (b) The results of both rated and unrated players in a round-robin tournament are taken into account. For unrated players, the average rating of the competition 'Rc' is also the tournament average 'Ra' determined as follows:
>   (i) Determine the average rating of the rated players 'Rar'.
>   (ii) Determine p for each of the rated players against all their opponents.
>   Then determine dp for each of these players.
>   Then determine the average of these dp = 'dpa'.
>   (iii) 'n' is the number of opponents.
>   Ra = Rar - dpa x n/(n+1)
>
> 8.22 If he scores 50%, then Ru = Ra
>
> 8.23 If he scores more than 50%, then Ru = Ra + 20 for each half point scored over 50%
>
> 8.24 If he scores less than 50% in a Swiss or team tournament:  Ru = Ra + dp
>
> 8.25 If he scores less than 50% in a round-robin: Ru = Ra + dp x n/(n+1)

Let's say you play in a Swiss and lose to a 2000, beat an 1800, draw to a 1900, draw a 1750, and lose to a 1950.

The first step is to calculate the average rating of your opponents. In this example, it is 1880. Since you scored less than 50%, we then calculate dp using table 8.1a (which is at the link.) You scored 2/5, which is 40% or 0.4. According to the table, this gives a dp of -72. So your rating for this tournament would be 1880 - 72 = 1808.

When your opponents are calculating their own ratings, this applies:

> 8.52  If the opponent is unrated, then the rating is determined at the end of the event. This applies only to round-robin tournaments. In other tournaments games against unrated opponents are not rated.

So your games against them would not count towards their ratings, in this case. But if this was a round-robin instead, then your rating would be calculated first (using the slightly more complicated process for round-robins described above), and their win expectancy against you would then be determined based on your new rating.